# Curly brace ( { ) in new line

Tags: clang, clang-format

I use clang-format (v6) for formating C/C++ code.

I configure "BraceWrapping" in .clang-format that all be in new line.

But I have any problem in one case.

[See Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UHzZc.png) for better understand. I want to make as left on picture.

.clang-format file is:

```
BraceWrapping:
  AfterClass:      true
  AfterControlStatement: true
  AfterEnum:       true
  AfterFunction:   true
  AfterNamespace:  true
  AfterObjCDeclaration: true
  AfterStruct:     true
  AfterUnion:      true
  AfterExternBlock: true
  BeforeCatch:     true
  BeforeElse:      true
  IndentBraces:    false
  SplitEmptyFunction: true
  SplitEmptyRecord: true
  SplitEmptyNamespace: true
```

Comment: Unfortunately, clang-format does not appear to support this. 

But I should point out: 1) it's better to provide code in your question, rather than a picture or a link to a picture, 2) you should specify which version of clang-format you're using (though it doesn't matter in this case) and 3) to use those `BraceWrapping` flags, you also must set `BreakBeforeBraces: Custom`.

Comment: Ok, thanks very much
1)  In the future I will post code in question or post link for picture.
2) I use clang-format version 6
3) I was researched define config commands for .clang-format file, and I understand to I must  set "BreakBeforeBraces" by "Custom" if I want to use curly braces  by desired mode.